# Extracting data from table with Scrapy

Tags: scrapy, html-table

I have this table

```
<table class="specs-table"> 
  <tbody> 
    <tr> 
      <td colspan="2" class="group">Sumary</td> 
    </tr> 
    <tr> 
      <td class="specs-left">Name</td> 
      <td class="specs-right">ROG GL552JX   </td> 
    </tr> 
    <tr class="noborder-bottom"> 
      <td class="specs-left">Category</td> 
      <td class="specs-right">Gaming    </td> 
    </tr> 
    <tr> 
      <td colspan="2" class="group">Technical Details</td> 
    </tr> 
    <tr> 
      <td class="specs-left">Name</td> 
      <td class="specs-right">Asus 555 </td>
      </tr> 
    <tr> 
      <td class="specs-left">Resolution </td> 
      <td class="specs-right">1920 x 1080 pixels </td>
    </tr>  
    <tr class="noborder-bottom"> 
      <td class="specs-left"> Processor </td> 
      <td class="specs-right"> 2.1 GHz  </td> 
    </tr>  
  </tbody> 
</table>
```

From this table I want my Scrapy to find the first occurrence of the text "Name" and to copy the value from the next cell (In this case "ROG GL552JX") and find the next occurrence of the text "Name" and copy the value "Asus 555".

The result I need:

```
'Name': [u'Asus 555'],
'Name': [u'Asus 555'],
```

The problem is that in this table I have two occurrences of the text "Name" and Scrapy copies the value of both occurrences.

My result is:

```
'Name': [u'ROG GL552JX', u'Asus 555'],
```

My bot:

```
def parse(self, response):
    next_selector = response.xpath('//*[@aria-label="Pagina urmatoare"]//@href')
    for url in next_selector.extract():
        yield Request(urlparse.urljoin(response.url, url))

    item_selector = response.xpath('//*[contains(@class, "pb-name")]//@href')
    for url in item_selector.extract():
        yield Request(urlparse.urljoin(response.url, url), callback=self.parse_item)


def parse_item(self, response):
    l = ItemLoader(item = PcgItem(), response=response, )

    l.add_xpath('Name', 'Name', '//tr/td[contains(text(), "Name")]/following-sibling::td/text()',', MapCompose(unicode.strip, unicode.title))
    return l.load_item()
```

How can I solve this problem?
Thank you

Comment: please correct the code, it fails on indentation and your `add_xpath` shouldn't work

Answer (score 0):

if you need an item per `Name`, then you should do something like:

```
for sel in response.xpath('//tr/td[contains(text(), "Name")]/following-sibling::td/text()'):
    l = ItemLoader(...)
    l.add_value('Name', sel.extract_first())
    ...
    yield l.load_item()
```

Now if you want it all inside an item, I would recommend to leave it as it is (a list) because an `scrapy.Item` is a dictionary, so you won't be able to have 2 `Name` as keys.